# ENOENT recieved on recv system call on a network socket

Tags: network-programming, boost-asio

In my C++ client i am using boost apis to perform send and receive of data to a server.
But once in a while when I am reading from the socket boost reports system error 2 which corresponds to "ENOENT" (No such file or directory).

Can any one tell in which condition can ENOENT be returned in recv/recvmsg system call ?

Comment: You should not be able to get `ENOENT` from a network socket. Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that causes the error and show us?

Comment: There is no ENOENT code in boost::asio error codes list http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/asio/error.hpp Need the example code.

Answer (score 3):

There was mis-interpretation of error code. system error code 2 in boost corresponds to EOF which occurs when sending entity has closed the socket while receiving entity is still performing read